# PHP Zend on Mac delivers raw PHP to browser

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've been developing a PHP application using the Zend framework for awhile on a Linux-based hosting provider, and it's gone along more or less swimmingly.

The time has come to be able to develop locally on my Mac, so I configured Apache to run PHP, grabbed the source code, and symlinked /Library/WebServer/Documents to the public/ folder in my Zend web app.

That was fine. The controllers were executing and loading the correct scripts, which seemed to parse and render correctly. Except, I wasn't able to connect to my local MySQL database. I realized that I hadn't copied /etc/php.ini.default to /etc/php.ini, so I went ahead and did that. I then updated this line:
    pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
and restarted Apache. Now, suddenly, none of the PHP executes. Instead, the raw PHP is sent back to the browser.

The effect is more or less the same as if I was trying to load a .php file directly with an Apache instance that didn't recognize the .php file extension. Based on what I've experienced, I'm guessing that maybe somewhere in php.ini there is a setting that is causing this to happen (when I rename php.ini and restart Apache, the scripts once again parse and render correctly, but again I can't hit the database) but I'm not sure where to look. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Please post/read apache log as it starts and as it fails to present the script...

Comment: You're saying that the PHP was running okay until you added php.ini? Cause it sounds more like an Apache configuration problem to me.

Comment: @Frankie, I checked /private/var/log/apache2/error_log, and there's nothing being printed there. Are there any other logs I can look at?

Comment: @ultranaut, that's right. PHP runs fine if Apache starts up with no php.ini; as soon as php.ini is back in place and I restart Apache, PHP won't execute. It does sound like an Apache issue, but php.ini is the determining factor.

Comment: Also, I tried running a standalone PHP script from the public/ directory, and it renders correctly. So Zend is also a factor in this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is reading this, here's the answer that I finally discovered:

short_open_tag = On

The above needs to be set in php.ini, particularly because all of my controllers, models, helpers, etc were using short tags (e.g. ), as is common with Zend applications.